# Ember 2.4.3 registration form using account and user model

Tags: json, ember.js

I am right now facing the signup form in Ember2.4.3. The problem is I have two model account and user, where account belongs to user and user belongs to account.

in my signup.js route,

```
model() {
  return this.store.createRecord('account');
}
```

where as in form I have added like

```
{{input type="text" class="form form-input-big" value=model.owner.firstName }}
{{input type="text" class="form form-input-big" value=model.owner.lastName }}
{{input type="text" class="form form-input-big" value=model.owner.email }}
{{input type="text" class="form form-input-big" value=model.owner.username }}
{{input type="text" class="form form-input-big" value=model.kind }}
```

model for account is

```
user: DS.belongsTo('user'),
kind: DS.attr('string')
```

where user has firstname, lastname, email and username.

When I use account as a model for signup form, the user: { data: { type: "owner", id: "null" }  } in the jsonapi response. Would like to know add other attributes like firstname, lastname and email with this request in JsonAPI?

Can anyone help me here, that would be great.

Comment: `model: this.store.createRecord('account');` this is invalid

Comment: model.user.firstName model.user.lastName model.user.email and so on, and on, just model.kind for account.kind. Or just replace that `owner` with `user` in the form snippet

Comment: @przemo_li Thanks. I have changed owner in model account but still the same error. Checking that issue. If any anything else am i missing out?

Comment: @przemo_li: Interestingly,  I am getting ```content' property of object proxy <(subclass of Ember.ObjectProxy):ember592>``` error now. After adding ```value=model.user.firstname```

Comment: Oh. Ok. Which object should be created first `account` or `user`?

Comment: @przemo_li the users should be created first as for as now.

Comment: Then use action to push form values up to the controller, first create user model, and fill the data, and then create account fill the data and attach previously created user model.

Comment: Thanks. Now I have changed my route as `return account: this.store.createRecord('account', { 'owner': this.store.createRecord('user'))` . Since the owner is subclass and proxyobject of model account, I couldn't send the owner details in the jsonapi attributes. Any idea how to solve this?